# How to set 2 different value for a typescript interface prop that depends on other prop value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this Toast component with 2 different sizes. If user set `smallSize` to `true` then `duration` value should be 4000 | 5000 | 6000. If not small then `duration` value should be 6000 | 7000 | 8000. By doing this I can restrict consumer from picking only certain numbers depending on whether they picked `smallSize` or not. But how can I achieve that? Right now, I just included every possible number in duration, but it's not ideal way.

```
interface IToast {
  id: string;
  open: boolean;
  smallSize?: boolean;
  title?: string;
  content: string;
  duration?: 4000 | 5000 | 6000 | 7000 | 8000 | null;
}

const Toast = (props: IToast): JSX.Element => {
  const {
    id,
    open = false,
    smallSize = false,
    title,
    content = "",
    duration = null,
  } = props;

  return <></>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define two separate interfaces that extend IToast

```
interface IToast {
  id: string;
  open: boolean;
  title?: string;
  content: string;
}

interface ISmallToast extends IToast {
  smallSize: true;
  duration?: 4000 | 5000 | 6000 | null;
}

interface ILargeToast extends IToast {
  smallSize?: false;
  duration?: 6000 | 7000 | 8000 | null;
}
```

and then use them like this

```
const Toast = (props: ISmallToast | ILargeToast) => {}
```

this way, whenever `smallSize` is true the duration can only have the values defined in `ISmallToast` and if `smallSize` is false or undefined then the duration can only have the values defined in `ILargeToast`

Comment: I tried this way and it does work, but I need to set smallSize as mandatory not optional. When I set `smallSize?` as optional then pass in false as default value for smallSize, then when I tested Toast component, without setting any value for smallSize, it was taking 4000 value for duration without type error. Is there a way to keep smallSize? as optional and make this work?

Comment: As far as I know, giving a default value while destructuring doesn't work well with discriminated union. You will be able to apply a constraint when passing in props but won't be able to distinguish between them inside the component if you use default values like this. Please check this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50139